# Spring5.1.5.RELEASE: No such method: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()

Tags: spring

After update Spring-framework to 5.1.5.RELEASE from 4.3.2.RELEASE,
I get an Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
```

I have spent two days looking for possible solution, but I find nothing help.

whole message:

```
[ERROR 2019-02-25 12:51:45.224] [resin-20] [] (FrameworkServlet.java:533) [Context initialization failed]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:715) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:590) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:70) ~[javaee-16.jar:?]
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletConfigImpl.createServletImpl(ServletConfigImpl.java:1358) ~[resin.jar:4.0.55]
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletConfigImpl.createServlet(ServletConfigImpl.java:1254) ~[resin.jar:4.0.55]
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletConfigImpl.createServlet(ServletConfigImpl.java:1205) ~[resin.jar:4.0.55]
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletManager.init(ServletManager.java:251) ~[resin.jar:4.0.55]
    at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebApp.startImpl(WebApp.java:3838) ~[resin.jar:4.0.55]
    at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebApp.access$700(WebApp.java:208) ~[resin.jar:4.0.55]
    at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebApp$StartupTask.run(WebApp.java:5390) ~[resin.jar:4.0.55]
    at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173) ~[resin.jar:4.0.55]
    at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118) ~[resin.jar:4.0.55]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.configureParameterNameProvider(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:314) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:290) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 25 more
```

Parent project pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Subject project Pom:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try maven clean, install and build the project. That will help.
The project actually pointing to old sources so that it's giving this error.

Comment: It does not work. Thank you Harshal Patil. But it works well for Tomcat. There may be a confliction about validation-api, but I did not find any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar in resin/lib.