# Spring upgrade to 5.3.21: No such method: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()

Tags: java, spring, maven

After upgrading Spring 5.3.21, and on Jboss 6 server startup getting below error.

Request if someone faced similar issue, to provide any inputs.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.configureParameterNameProvider(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:346) [spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:309) [spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40) [spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
```

Followed this link, but still same issue - [Spring5.1.5.RELEASE: No such method: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859722/spring5-1-5-release-no-such-method-javax-validation-configuration-getdefaultpa)

Below is complete pom -

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketbox</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.monitorjbl</groupId>
            <artifactId>xlsx-streamer</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-xml</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-management</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-json-basic</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-addr</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-wsdl</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.201812061821-r</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Output of  mvn compile dependency:tree -Dverbose

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.3.21)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.3.21)
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.picketbox:picketbox:jar:4.1.1.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.21:test
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test - omitted for conflict with 1.5.1.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test - omitted for conflict with 1.5.1.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.1:test - omitted for conflict with 2.17.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:test - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:test - omitted for conflict with 5.3.21)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:test - omitted for conflict with 1.30)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test - omitted for conflict with 1.5.1.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test - omitted for conflict with 2.2.0)
[INFO] |  +- (junit:junit:jar:4.12:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:test - omitted for conflict with 5.3.21)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:test - omitted for conflict with 5.3.21)
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver:ojdbc6:jar:12.1.0.2.0:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test - omitted for conflict with 5.0.4)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:test - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] +- jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.17:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1)
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:4.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.05:compile
[INFO] +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4.01)
[INFO] +- net.sf.supercsv:super-csv:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jxls:jxls-reader:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.2)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.1)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.1)
[INFO] +- com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:4.0.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.1)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:4.0.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.1)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:4.0.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.0.1)
[INFO] |  +- com.rackspace.apache:xerces2-xsd11:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.rackspace.eclipse.webtools.sourceediting:org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor:jar:2.1.100:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- edu.princeton.cup:java-cup:jar:10k:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.b2)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.1)
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-management:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-json-basic:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.1)
[INFO] |  +- (wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.2)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:jar:5.2.0.201812061821-r:compile
[INFO]    +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:compile
[INFO]    +- com.jcraft:jzlib:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO]    \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
```

[stacktrace screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRsKQ.png)

Comment: Can you run the following `mvn dependency:tree` and add the results please?  I'm guessing you may have multiple conflicting versions of the javax validation API

Comment: thanks Taylor. Edited post and included dependency tree.

Comment: huh, you only have one validation jar.  Which version of spring were you on before?  Also, not sure if this is possible but can you start the app without JBoss?  E.g. locally or on tomcat or some such.

Comment: @Taylor Previously was using 4.3.5 release. Also validation-api was not used prior and it still worked. After upgrade, to mitigate that startup error, I added validation-api 2.0.1.Final dependency. Also hibernate-validator  5.2.4.Final was used prior, but I felt it's not needed now and I removed now.

Comment: Attached stacktrace screenshot, if it helps to troubleshoot

Comment: So the version of the validation api you're using does have the method.  I'm not familiar with JBoss, but many of these enterprise app servers will override your class dependencies with their own, I know I've seen weblogic do this.  I suspect you're running into this.  I'd suggest looking for jboss config to use WAR/EAR classes instead of embedded.